# kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar Error on Ubuntu 18.04 in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I never wanted to ask because I always view Stackoverflow as a guest user to solve my problems. But time I am facing a very big problem in Android Studio on my Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

[image: Kotlin error when ever I create a new project]

I am a new linux user just installed it yesterday. I am using windows for more than 8 years and very good in it. I bought this laptop this march month with i3 7th gen and 4gb ram intel hd 620.
I learned Kotlin language and now to use my kotlin skills I need to use Android Studio but when I installed it on my windows 10 it was working slowly even my PC is very clean and fast and this same error I was facing on my Windows. So I installed Linux Ubuntu in 250GB Partiton from my 1tb HDD and installed Android Studio and got the same error I am sstuck to this problem for so many time and do 24 hours trying to solve but I can't I am in very tension about this. Please any programmer help me in the very simple way. Because its my dream life and love.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to give more information about your error message, including anything else that log message might have said (for example by clicking on "Open Messages View" and "Show Log in Files" that Android Studio shows). Copy-paste any text you think is relevant; screenshots of error messages are discouraged

Comment: I just fixed it right now 1 min ago. I downloaded all the necessary automatic downloading files of Android studio problem was in my wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on #Linux mint.
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle

Uncheck Offline work in Global Gradle Settings.

It worked for me if still doesn't then try 
File -> Invalidate cache/Restart